# React component with Pagination and search issue

Tags: reactjs

Having issues with my search for some reason I have an error saying:

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, the below variable is the problem I guess.

```
const maxPages = Math.floor(movies.length / PAGE_SIZE);
```

Also looks like the search doesn't display the right number of movies.
Any help much appreciated. [Demo here](https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/dyRvvWB?editors=0011)

Comment: The imdb external API is sending errors in some cases
Response: "False"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the response from the API always be an array

```
setMovies(response.data.Search || []);
```

Comment: yea, that seems to fix the issue! yeye! great, do you know why always shows no more than 10 results?

Comment: I believe the API is limited, not in the code

Comment: @iunflix, no really cos I had working before and I've done some changes to display only 8 items per page and I broke the search and now shows only 10 per page

Comment: @iunflix the movies.length is the issue! doesn't display the movies properly...

Answer (score 0):

The external API is sending errors in some cases
check  Response: "False" or "True"
consider it as API error if Response = "False"
so response.data.Search will only be there if Response if true otherwise data.search is undefined.

Check network

Also try to add at least three characters to search
only call API when at least three characters is entered in text box

also no need of UI side pagination
send page={pageNumber}
for the pagination
API already support server-side pagination

[image]